# Cannot add records to an RDD from inside if-else

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD and I want to "concatenate" this RDD with another one (that has the same type of content) and `union` was a fitting method. However, before I concatenate the rdds I want to make sure my collection fulfills some requirements (hence the if-statement) and after that unite the rdds. Unfortunately unions as described in the code below do not persist outside the loop. Is there a way to make this happen? Incrementally add more entries to the original RDD `rdd` from inside if-else ? If there is no if_else union works just fine.

```
var rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq[String]())

val (!collection.isEmpty) {
    val value = collection.map(_._2)
    rdd.union(value)
}
```

Comment: is that the complete code? I don't see any if else statements.

Comment: No, that's just a simple snippet of the format. There is no else actually although it doesn't matter any way because what happens inside the block does not persist.

Comment: did you see my answer below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what I understand from your question that you have two `rdds` as

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq("a", "b", "c"))
val collection = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "d"), (2, "e")))
```

And you want to `union` them after checking some conditions which can be done by defining a function

```
def unionRdd(originalRdd: RDD[String], testCollection: RDD[(Int, String)]): RDD[String] ={
  if(!collection.isEmpty()){
    val value = collection.map(_._2)
    originalRdd.union(value)
  }
  else{
    originalRdd
  }
}
```

And you can call the function as

```
val unionedRDD = unionRdd(rdd, collection)
```

Which should give you the concatenated `RDD` after checking certain conditions defined in `unionRdd` function

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thanks, that actually works but the concept is very similar to mine. Why does it work when I pack this as a subroutine instead of in a bigger routine where only the if-statement is present? Just curious.

Comment: Thats because the function is supposed to return so the compiler seeks for return value. Compiler doesn't get any value to return in case if condition fails. So we need else. :) I hope its clear

Comment: thanks for acceptance and an upvote :) feeling great that it helped